# 7-Zip command line - do not extract certain file types

Tags: command-line, zip, 7-zip

How do I extract all the files in a 7-Zip .7z archive EXCEPT certain file types, using the  7-Zip command line?

Example:
backup.7z contains files of type:

- .xls
- .xlsx
- .doc
- .docx
- .pdf
- .txt
- .png
- .gif

Using the 7-Zip command line, how do I extract all the files from that backup.7z archive EXCEPT the .doc and .docx files?

The .7z archive contains files and folders and I want all the files and folders - EXCEPT the .doc and .docx files - to be extracted.

I am using MS Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How do I extract all the files in a 7-Zip .7z archive EXCEPT certain file types

Use the `-x` (Exlude filenames) switch.

7z e backup.7z -x!*.doc*

---

#### -x (Exclude filenames) switch

> Specifies which filenames or wildcarded names must be excluded from
>   the operation.
>
> Multiple exclude switches are supported.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> -x[<recurse_type>]<file_ref>
>
> <recurse_type> ::= r[- | 0]
> <file_ref> ::= @{listfile} | !{wildcard}
> ```
>
> See `-i` (Include) switch description for information about option
>   parameters.
>
> **Examples**
>
> ```
> 7z a -tzip archive.zip *.txt -x!temp.*
> ```
>
> adds to the archive archive.zip all *.txt files, except temp.* files.
>
> Commands that can be used with this switch
>
> `a` (Add), `d` (Delete), `e` (Extract), `l` (List), `t` (Test), `u`
>   (Update), `x` (Extract with full paths)

Source [-x (Exclude filenames) switch](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/exclude.htm)

Comment: Is this the best way to exclude multiple file types: `7z x backup.7z -oC:\temp -x!*.mp3 -x!*.mp4 -x!*.swf -x!*.ppt -x!*.psd`

Comment: I don't know. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I have tried it and it works. But is there a better way to write that code?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me and 'aos' parameter will skip existing files.

```
7za x '-xr!*.mp3.bin' '-aos' file
```

```
# nice -n 18 7za x '-xr!*.mp3.bin' '-aos' Environment-voice-20190106-20190108-20230717101500.zip

7-Zip (a) [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=C.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,16 CPUs Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8272CL CPU @ 2.60GHz (50657),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 1386663243 bytes (1323 MiB)

Extracting archive: Environment-voice-20190106-20190108-20230717101500.zip
--
Path = Environment-voice-20190106-20190108-20230717101500.zip
Type = zip
Physical Size = 1386663243
64-bit = +

 94% 1289
... Everything is Ok

Files: 2930
Size:       27653690
Compressed: 1386663243
```